# entity framework join

Tags: entity-framework, join

i have 2 table (user, user_profile) without a explicit relationship in the sql db. and i can't add it to the db.

so, i can't do this:

```
db.user.include("user_profile")
```

the attribute in for the join is user_id

is possible do anything like this?

```
db.user.join("user_profile On user.id = user_profile.user_id")
```

How can i do that?

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051612/entity-framework-join-3-tables

Answer (score 5):

Try this :

```
from u in db.user
join up in db.user_profile on u.id equals up.user_id
select new { u, up};
```