# C# - Entity Framework - Join method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a table called "PublicUserOfferingSignUp" which contains the following columns.

- Id
- PublicUserId - foreign key to PublicUser.Id
- OfferingId
- Created

My application is using Entity Framework, but I am getting stuck with how to join from the PublicUserOfferingSignUp table to the PublicUser table.

I want to obtain a list of PublicUserOfferingSignUp records but ordered by the Name column of the PublicUser table.

Currently I have this ....

```
return DataBase.PublicUserOfferingSignUps.Join(PublicUser,
```

But I can't seem to work it out, any ideas ....

Steven

Can anybody help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [entity framework join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044153/entity-framework-join)

Answer (score 4):

Something like that

```
DataBase.PublicUserOfferingSignUps.Join(Database.PublicUsers, 
    puosu => puosu.PublicUserId,//PublicUserOfferingSignUps key
    pu => pu.Id,//PublicUser key
    (puosu, pu) => new {
        publicUsersOfferingSignUp = puosu,//we take all data from PubliUserOfferingSignUps
        puName = pu.Name//and Name from PublicUser
        })
.OrderBy(x => x.puName)//we order by PublicUser Name
.Select(x => x.publicUsersOfferingSignUp );//we take only the PublicOfferingSignUps
```

Edit : as @M.Schenkel noticed, it would be easier to have a

```
public virtual PublicUser PublicUser {get;set;}
```

in your `PublicUserOfferingSignUp` model

then the query would be

```
DataBase.PublicUserOfferingSignUps
.OrderBy(puosu => puosu.PublicUser.Name);
```

easier, no ?

Comment: so what does this return? I want to return a list of PublicUserOfferingSignUp records

Comment: Yes, your question was rather clear... try it and if I missed something, I'll be glad to correct ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you use the Entity Framework, the public user should be a property of your PublicUserOfferingSignUp-entity. If not, you can write a LINQ query to join them. For example:

```
var result = from pu in context.PublicUserOfferingSignUp
join u in context.PublicUser on u.id equals pu.PublicUserId 
select pu;
```

(this code is untested, but should give you the idea).